# How to properly deploy a swagger project?

Tags: swagger

Hi I have an API built with swagger. I need to deploy it to my production server and keep it running. How can I do this? Like a normal node project? What tools I can use to deploy it?

Comment: How about [Swaggerhub](https://swaggerhub.com/api-deployment/)? I know [muleSoft](https://www.mulesoft.com/) provides deployment as well

Comment: @Dana Actually I wanted to host in my own server for now :-)